# Iterate through two variables in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
CategoryID    Days   Views
    a          1      19
    a          2     2000
    a          5     5667
    a          7     7899
    b          1      2
    b          3     245
    c          1      1
    c          2     252
    c          7     2657
```

Given a `threshold = n`, I want to create two lists and I'll append them until I reach that threshold + 1 element for each category.

So, if `n < 4`, I expect for category `a`:

```
days_list = [1,2,5]
views_list = [19, 2000, 5667]
```

After that, I want to apply a function in those lists and then, start the iteration in the next category. However, I'm facing two issues with the following code:

1. I can't iterate properly when `i == 0`
2. The iteration does not go to the next category.

```
df['interpolated'] = int
days_list = []
views_list = []



for i,post in enumerate(category):
    if df['category_id'].iloc[i-1] != post:
            days_list.append(df['days new'].iloc[i])
            views_list.append(df['views'].iloc[i])
    elif df['category_id'].iloc[i] == post and df[category_id].iloc[i-1] == post:
        if df['days new'].iloc[i] < 3:
            days_list.append(df['days new'].iloc[i])
            views_list.append(df['views'].iloc[i])
        elif df['days new'].iloc[i] != 3:
            days_list.append(df['days new'].iloc[i])
            views_list.append(df['views'].iloc[i])
            break
        # Calculate the interpolation
        interpolator = log_interp1d(days_list,views_list)
        df['interpolated'] = round(interpolator(4).astype(int))
    # Reset the lists after the category loop
    days_list = [] 
    views_list = []
```

Can someone give me some light? Thanks!

Comment: Provide an example of desired output?

Comment: Please show your expect output

Comment: No need to build lists. *"Create two lists and I'll append them until I reach that threshold + 1*" is much more simply stated in pandas as *"Group by CategoryID, then within each group, filter for `Days < Threshold`"*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a row_number type operation.

```
....
df['row_number'] = df.groupby(['CategoryId']).cumcount+1
```

Then, you will have a dataframe

```
CategoryID    Days   Views  row_number
    a          1      19        1
    a          2     2000       2
    a          5     5667       3
    a          7     7899       4
    b          1      2         1
    b          3     245        2
    c          1      1         1
    c          2     252        2
    c          7     2657       3
```

Then, you should be able to use boolean filtering to get what you want. So for your example,

`df_category_a_filtered_4 = df[(df['row_number'] == 3]) & (df['CategoryID'] == 'a')]`

Which will filter your dataframe so that the two lists you want are the two columns. This can be functionized obviously to do whatever you need.

If you want a more specific output, please specify what that would look like.